# Accentued vowels and ñ not showing properly in internet explorer 11

Tags: .htaccess, utf-8, character-encoding, internet-explorer-11, utf

I have finished a website and some characters of spanish are not showing right in some systems with windows 7 and IE11.
I installed a virtual machine with these specifications but can't reproduce the bug, so I'm unable to check my changes...

My system is W8 with IE 11 and is showing fine.

I added the following line to .htaccess at line 1.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

These are the fonts set in .css

```
* {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
```

This is the first line in the head tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Characters giving problems are ñ and accented vowels like áéíóú.
I changed a ñ to `&ntilde;` in the text to check if it could be a html entities issue, but the client reports no changes.

Response headers in the inspector of chrome:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 17:34:23 GMT Server: Apache
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 2256
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=500 Connection: Keep-Alive
>       Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

The file is a php that includes another script as the first line:

```
   <?php include 'otherfile.php'; ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This other php loads variables to show later in the body or processes ajax requests and returns some html and dies after that.

Any help is welcome. Also if you happen to reproduce the bug, please tell me how-to.

The url is [valarquitectura.com](http://valarquitectura.com)

Comment: It might be that not the encoding is the problem, but the installed fonts which simply lack those chars. That might explain why you cannot reproduce that with your virtual machine and could be the case depending on what MS-Windows version is installed. I suggest to safe the page locally on one of those systems and check the file afterwards using a hexeditor to take a _real_ look at the encoding IE received / uses.

Comment: I also have thought about that, but how could I solve it to show for everyone if the client requests an specific font. And the same font, is showing special chars in some systems and not in others¿?

Also if this were true, the font lacks those chars, but is not falling back to the other specified fonts. I guess it's no surprise

Comment: Expressions like “are not showing right” are not problem descriptions. Describe what you see, and post sample code with actual HTTP headers or at least a URL.

Comment: It is questionable if it really is "the same font" in all systems. As you state yourself browsers use a fallback strategy when it comes to selecting a matching font. Maybe such a system falls back to an ascii only font?

Comment: Characters giving problems are ñ and accented vowels like áéíóú.
For example "diseño" shows as "diseyo"

Comment: I don't know how could I check with an hex editor the saved html or how to check the font that is really showing in the browser, any insight or links about that?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have updated the post with the url at the end

Comment: So what is the problem? The URL mentioned refers to page that has a strange logo “VäLArchitectura”, but that’s an image. In texts, Spanish letters seem to work OK. Please specify what the *problem* is, in observable terms, and provide code that actually reproduces it.

Comment: The logo is just like that... you can see it's an image ;D
In the menu Select > Servicios > Diseño 
It should be Diseño the last item, but in some systems it shows as Diseyo (Y instead of Ñ). 
In those systems it also happens in all parts of the text where it hsould be an á é í ó ú, like "certificados energéticos", that é shows as another character instead.
But, I can't reproduce the bug in my computer. (I was at the client's computer and it's true, and also other users reported it)